# Recurly - Token invalid or expired - how to find more info on error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, recurly

I'm integrating my Rails 4 app with Recurly. I'm using Recurly.js v3 to get a billing token and then v2 of the API via the Ruby Gem.

Everything was working both locally and on heroku until I changed the API credentials (`RECURLY_SUBDOMAIN`, `RECURLY_JS_PRIVATE_KEY`, `RECURLY_API_KEY`) in my .env file over to a different recurly account for production. Now I'm getting an error response from Recurly:

```
>>ERROR -- Recurly: <=== 404 Not Found (948.3ms)
>><error>
>>  <symbol>token_invalid</symbol>
>>  <description>Token is either invalid or expired</description>
>></error>
```

The token is not expired as the request for the token information takes place directly before the API Subscription request. And I can't find information on why a token would be invalid. It's already passed the Recurly.js validations on the card as it has returned the token in the first place so I think it's not a problem with the card.

Here is my call to recurly.js for a token - this is executed on submit of `views\devise\registrations\new.html.erb` form:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function(){
  if($('.registrations.new, .registrations.edit').length){
    if(!recurly.configured)
      recurly.configure('<%=Recurly.js.private_key%>') ;

    var form = $('#card-form');
    var subscription = {
      setupForm: function() {
        return form.submit(function() {
          event.preventDefault();
          if ($('#card_number').length) {
            recurly.token(form, subscription.tokenHandler);
            return false;
          } else {
           return true;
          }
        });
      },
      tokenHandler: function(err, token) {
       //console.log(token); at this point returns a different token each time
       if(err){
         //error message rendered
       } else {
         //card token applied to field in devise registrations form and form submitted
         $('#user_card_token').val(token.id)
         $('#card-form')[0].submit()
       }
     }   
   };
   subscription.setupForm();
  }
});
```

I have created a before_create hook on my devise user that calls the Recurly API:

```
In models/user.rb

before_create :create_subscription

def create_subscription
  #logger.info card_token at this point returns the token received in the js above
  subscription = Recurly::Subscription.create!(
    plan_code: plan,
    account:  {
      account_code: recurly_account_code,
      email:        email,
      first_name:   first_name,
      last_name:    last_name,
      billing_info: {token_id: card_token}
    }
  )
rescue 
  errors.add :base, "Card Error"
  false
end
```

That is where the error occurs. Is there a way to find any more information on the validity of the token? Or any other suggestions for troubleshooting?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong key to configure Recurly.js.

```
recurly.configure('<%=Recurly.js.private_key%>') ;
```

should be

```
recurly.configure('PUBLIC_KEY');
```

Where the PUBLIC_KEY is the Public Key found on your API Access page here: https://app.recurly.com/go/developer/api_access

ref: https://docs.recurly.com/js/#getting-started

Comment: Thanks - so it seems the ruby Gem github README referenced a JS Private key from api v2 that confused things. I see you've updated that already!

Comment: Awesome! Yes, we'd love to clear up that bit of confusion for everyone. Thanks for the great feedback.